# Unity display glitches in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity

I'll just be using Unity, but every time I try to shut down, open the shortcuts guide, or open the Dash, I'm getting glitches. Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

The suspend and logout menus do the same thing as the shutdown one. Sometimes I can barely read them, depending on the wallpaper (it changes automatically).

The Dash does kind of the same thing, but **much** less noticeably.

It appears that the correct blurring and dimming/coloring only happens in that small square in the corner.

I'm running on a DELL Inspiron 6000 with a Intel® 915GM x86/MMX/SSE2 graphics card.

Comment: Check your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for error or warning messages.

Comment: By the way your wallpaper looks very cool

Comment: This sounds like a bug... Have you considered filing a bug report?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Fujitsu-Siemens Laptop running 13.04 with the same graphics card, and I had the same problem.  I have downloaded the graphics card driver form [Intel](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads), and installed it, and that took care of the problem.

Once you download the driver, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the folder where the file was downloaded, probably the Downloads folder, and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <package_name>
```